# iPhone SDK: Loading resources from custom URL scheme

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview

I have HTML string which is created using an xml file by a third party library. The HTML string contains custom URLs for images and videos (Ex:image://). Is there is way by I can handle these resource load request and load them correctly in UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a subclass of NSURLProtocol and re-implement the following methods that can handle the custom URL scheme

```
+(BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
+(NSURLRequest*)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
+(BOOL)requestIsCacheEquivalent:(NSURLRequest*)a toRequest:(NSURLRequest*)b
-(void)startLoading
-(void)stopLoading
```

We also have to register this custom URL protocol class when the app launches in the following way

```
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[CustomURLProtocol class]];
```

Comment: An implementation example would be nice.. it wasn't very clear at first what needs to be done in startLoading/stopLoading

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change them to a file:// url that points to a file inside the application bundle.

To get the path you can use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFileInResources" ofType:@".png"];
```

Note that you will need to escape this using:

```
NSString *escapedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```